# Создание кнопки для notifyIcon(Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма с кнопкой, после нажатии которой должен появиться `notifyicon`. Как сделать уведомление с кнопкой как на этой картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не NotifyIcon, это Toast notification, которая есть только в Windows 10.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А в Winforms ее можно использовать?

Comment: Да вроде способы были, лично не пробовал. В теории надо добавить ссылки на нужные dll винды, далее использовать что то, по типу [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification.%2523ctor)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.5)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396), ну и вроде надо сделать ярлык в `Start Menu` c указанием AppUserModel.ID и ToastActivatorCLSID

Comment: [Embedding .NET Controls to NotifyIcon Balloon Tooltip](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37912/Embedding-NET-Controls-to-NotifyIcon-Balloon-Toolt)